# In nodejs & express, what's the difference between settings & locals

Tags: node.js, express

Starting my way in node + express, what's the difference between:

```
app.set(key, value)
```

and

```
app.locals({key: value});
```

I've read the express docs and it states that app.locals are passed to all the rendered views, but I was also able to access the settings from a jade view as well (using #{settings.someKey}).
As both are available in jade templates I can't seem to figure out what the difference or different usage for the 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that by manipulating `app.locals` directly, you can create 'top level' variables for your templates, instead of having to use the `settings.` prefix.

`app.set(key, value)` is the same as `app.locals.settings[key] = value`; the former is the preferred way of configuring certain parts of Express (like setting `view engine`).

**EDIT:** small demo to show how they do the same:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.set('foo', 'bar');
console.log('app.get("foo"):', app.get('foo')); // 'bar'
console.log('app.locals.settings.foo:', app.locals.settings.foo); // 'bar'
app.locals.settings['foo'] = 'another bar';
console.log('2nd app.get("foo"):', app.get('foo')); // 'another bar'
```

Comment: ok thanks, just one thing in your answer is a bit confusing, when you say "app.set(key, value) is the same as app.locals.settings[key] = value", do you mean it's supposed to point to  the same object? From my testing the 2 were different objects. Am I missing something?

Comment: All of the above does works, however "console.log(app.locals.foo);" (not in your example) doesn't work. If I understand correctly, using app.set(k, v) creates a settings objects in app.locals. Is that a correct assumption? BTW thanks for the help!

Comment: Your assumption is correct, but I'm not sure I understand why you think that `app.locals.foo` would exist (since it isn't set by `app.set()`); `app.locals` is an object, `app.locals.settings` is also an object, but one which you can 'fill' using `app.set(KEY, VALUE)`, as well as directly using `app.locals.settings.KEY = VALUE` (or `app.locals.settings['KEY'] = VALUE`).

Comment: What I initially thought was that they are 2 different objects, an app.locals object and an app.settings object. I didn't realize that settings was a nested object in locals. Now it makes perfect sense, thanks for clearing this up.